# How to make it easy

Tags: kernel

I use to care about knowing how an Os worked. All those little bits, how to write a great shell script, how to whatever. I don't anymore. I don't want to know. It's something that happens later in your life. I think Ubuntu is AWESOME. I am quite taken back by its constant *need* for attention.

I want to make PCs loaded with Ubuntu for friends that no longer need what microsludge offers. I mean, have you seen Windose 10??!! Enuf said.

So here I am puzzling over how to make Ubuntu seamless to my non-techy friends. And I can't do it. I can't do it for the simple matter that the Ubuntu updater constantly fills the /boot (guessing) partition with old kernels until there is no room left on that partition.

Here is an issue should have been addressed and FIXED a decade ago.

Yea yeah, I found the command to fix it. THAT IS NOT WHAT I'M ASKING FOR OR SAYING.

Logic dictates one of you made a really bad decision long ago. Don't confess, just fix the bloody thing. When we do an Ubuntu install, give us the option to automatically delete old kernels and the other junk none of us need anymore. How hard is that?

I want it idjut proof. Something no one will mess with less'en they got a clue. I want it simple.

P.S. Using the words simple or simply shows you are one heck of a ignorant writer. What may be simple to you will not be simple to me. GUARANTEED. Be a great writer, don't bloody use those two words ANYWHERE.

Comment: Tip: People don't like being talked down to, especially when you are asking them for help. People also don't appreciate unwanted advice.

Comment: IMHO Ubuntu is no more difficult than any other OS, don't confuse familiar with easy. If you do is log in and web browse or use word processing Ubuntu is as easy as anything else and, at least IMHO, Ubuntu is more trouble free then Windows, no need to constantly scan for malware in Ubuntu ;)

Comment: and always read the manual, the man page or tips and tricks on the web

Comment: The solution to this is really really simple, simply read the manuals, there are so many around the web, IMO I think Ubuntu is a great OS and there are hundreds of people each day dedicating private unpaid time into making it better. So **YOU** should dedicate at least a tiny bit of your private unpaid time to get knowing the matter.

Answer (score 7):

> When we do an Ubuntu install, give us the option to automatically delete old kernels and the other junk none of us need anymore. How hard is that?

Deleting old kernels is simple. Doing it automatic is NOT. Please tell me you know of a definition for "old kernels". In my professional opinion (yes I maintain servers) the automated system needs to stay away from my kernels. =I= decide when they get removed and =I= never want them removed. Removing kernels is taking a risk that I do not want to take.

> I want it idiot proof. Something no one will mess with less'en they got a clue. I want it simple.

Idiot proof is never going to happen. It is impossible to cover all methods all the idiots in the world can think of. But ... Even idiots can make and restore a backup. And a backup makes mistakes trivial.

> I can't do it for the simple matter that the Ubuntu updater constantly fills the /boot (guessing) partition with old kernels until there is no room left on that partition.

A professional fixes this problem by creating a large enough /boot, either no partition for /boot or prepare a scenario where /boot can be enlarged.

It takes 1 symlink to get /boot enlarged if none of these are possible.